# Node.js/Express: Pass routes/ let other routes than root handle by the Single page application

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vue.js, routes

I have a node.js /Express server set up that serves my Single page application (in Vue.js) inside the public folder from the root url path(localhost:3333).

Now, inside my index.html from my SPA, I can navigate easily inside my app to other pages (those are all handled by the vue.js History API, (not the hash one)).

However, if I enter directly some route inside my browser, which should point to some subpage in my SPA (e.g localhost:3333/about.html), that route is trying to be served from my node.js program which of course does not recognize that route...

How can I let handle this route by my SPA directly, and not through my node.js program? I found some sort of solution, by redirecting everything not root url to let it serve the index.html page in my dist SPA folder:

```
app.all('/*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('index.html', {root: publicDir});
});
```

First, I do not really understand how this can be handled by my SPA... I know that I serve my index.html page but it kind of redirects itself to the /about subpage by my Vue app automatically or how does it work?

And secondly, is that the recommended / or even standard way how to pass that route handling to your SPA and not by node.js? Or is there another better way?

Answer (score 0):

Like you already said in your explanation, you have a SPA and the routing is being handled by Vue in the frontend. Retuning your `index.html` for every route and letting Vue do its thing in the frontend is the way to go.

**And secondly, is that the recommended / or even standard way how to pass that route handling to your SPA and not by node.js? Or is there another better way?**

The other options would be to have a server site app, meaning building the page on everything request. What [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) does in React.

Or to have static pages, like what [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/) does in React.